# why my c program for won't work by receiving number as string and using that as int array....help me get clear view about string and int array

Tags: arrays, c, string

I try to receive number as string or char array and I want to change char into int. I am accessing it by index number. End i want to get odd digits sum and even digit sum

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    void main()
    {
        int length ,i, odd _sum=0,even_sum=0;
       char num1[100];
       //int num=0;
       
       printf("Enter the number : ");
       scanf("%s",&num1);
       
       printf("%s",num1[0]);
        
       length = strlen(num1);
       
       
       for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
       {
            if(i%2==0)
            { 
                **odd_sum = odd_sum + atoi(num1[i]);**
            }
            else
            {

                **even_sum = even_sum + atoi(num1[i]);**
            }
       }

        printf("\n odd number sum : %d \n",odd_sum);
        
        printf("even number sum : %d ",even_sum);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `atoi` expects a nul terminated string, not a single character. If you are certain that `num1[i]` is a digit then `num1[i] - '0';` will give you the numeric value.

Comment: The definition of odd_sum has a space in it: odd _sum. Remove the space,

Comment: When you say odd and even digits, do you really mean every other character, or do you mean digits which are odd or even?

Comment: Usually, counting odd or even digits starts with the lowest digit.  Yours starts with the highest, so which digits go in the odd sum or even sum depends on the length of the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, use `%c` to print a character, the counter should start from zero till before the length(removing `=` from the condition), use `char - '0'` to know the int value of a digit character and removed a forgotten space here `odd _sum=0`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
 int main()
{
    int length ,i, odd_sum=0,even_sum=0;
    char num1[100];
    //int num=0;

    printf("Enter the number : ");
    scanf("%s",&num1);

    printf("%c",num1[0]);

    length = strlen(num1);


    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            odd_sum = odd_sum + (num1[i] - '0');
        }
        else
        {

        even_sum = even_sum + (num1[i] - '0');
        }
    }

    printf("\n odd number sum : %d \n",odd_sum);

    printf("even number sum : %d ",even_sum);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much sir...thats help me a lot

Comment: Don't mention it!